# Laravel form request return authorization failed with custom message

Tags: php, laravel, exception, authorization

In my Laravel (7.x) application, I am using `ajax` to `validate & submit` the form. I am using `form request` to validate the field. Till here everything is working completely fine.

However, while handling the user authorization using `Laravel Gates`, I am getting exception instead of returning json errored response.

ValidateRequest.php:

```php
class ValidateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        # access
        return Gate::allows('admin');
    }

    ...
}
```

Here is the exception:

```json
{
    "message": "This action is unauthorized.",
    "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException",
    "file": "<path>\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php",
    "line": 225,
    "trace": [        
        ...
    ]
}
```

I need to set and return the custom message via ajax response.

Something like this:

```php
{
   'status': 422,
   'error': 'You are not authorized to access this area'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the [FormRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php)'s `failedAuthorization` protected method by adding this on your custom `FormRequest`:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;

...

protected function failedAuthorization()
{
    throw new AuthorizationException('Write your custom fail authorization message.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The deny function by default throws exception

```
protected function deny($message = 'This action is unauthorized.')
{
    throw new AuthorizationException($message);
}
```

So you should be able to change this in your guard, something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

Gate::define('edit-settings', function ($user) {
    if (! $user->isAdmin) {
        return json(['status' => '400', 'message' => 'your message']);
    }

    return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @dev_mustafa, but in which file do I write this code..?

Comment: in your gate file